# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION: No Core Dump Will Be Written

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, rxtx, jssc

I am attempting to write a serial communication class in Java that will connect to an Arduino UNO using the Java Simple Serial Connector library. Whenever I attempt to open the port, however, I run into this error with the Native Code:

> #
> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> #
> #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006ec4b5bb, pid=6324, tid=6508
> #
> # JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (14.0.2+12) (build 14.0.2+12-46)
> # Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
> # Problematic frame:
> # C  [jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll+0xb5bb]
> #
> # No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
> #
> # An error report file with more information is saved as:
> # C:\Users\Michael\eclipse-workspace\JSSC\hs_err_pid6324.log
> #
> # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
> #   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
> #

**The content of the log is as follows:**

```
---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages SerialTest

Host: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor         , 16 cores, 15G,  Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.546)
Time: Sat Dec  5 19:08:31 2020 Eastern Standard Time elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001f0ff92b000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=6508, stack(0x0000008325300000,0x0000008325400000)]

Stack: [0x0000008325300000,0x0000008325400000],  sp=0x00000083253ff2e0,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll+0xb5bb]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  jssc.SerialNativeInterface.openPort(Ljava/lang/String;Z)J+0
j  jssc.SerialPort.openPort()Z+65
j  SerialTest.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+23
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005), reading address 0xfffffffffe0fb7f0


Register to memory mapping:

RIP=0x000000006ec4b5bb jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll
RAX=0xfffffffffe0fb7f0 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000083253ff350 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
RCX=0x00007ffd3e42bf84 ntdll.dll
RDX=0x0 is NULL
RSP=0x00000083253ff2e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
RBP=0x00000083253ff460 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
RSI=0x000001f0ff92b310 points into unknown readable memory: a0 1a 55 03 fd 7f 00 00
RDI=0x0000000000000430 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000083253ff1d8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
R9 =0x00000083253ff2d0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
R10=0x0 is NULL
R11=0x0000000000000246 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000083253ff518 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
R13=0x000001f0ff93ff00 points into unknown readable memory: 5c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
R14=0x00000083253ff410 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f0ff92b000
R15=0x000001f0ff92b000 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0xfffffffffe0fb7f0, RBX=0x00000083253ff350, RCX=0x00007ffd3e42bf84, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x00000083253ff2e0, RBP=0x00000083253ff460, RSI=0x000001f0ff92b310, RDI=0x0000000000000430
R8 =0x00000083253ff1d8, R9 =0x00000083253ff2d0, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x0000000000000246
R12=0x00000083253ff518, R13=0x000001f0ff93ff00, R14=0x00000083253ff410, R15=0x000001f0ff92b000
RIP=0x000000006ec4b5bb, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00000083253ff2e0)
0x00000083253ff2e0:   000001f0a0add1e0 000001f0ff93fc90
0x00000083253ff2f0:   000000006ec4b210 000001f0fdf20000
0x00000083253ff300:   000001f0fe020000 0000000000000004
0x00000083253ff310:   000001f0ff92b310 0000000000000430
0x00000083253ff320:   00000083253ff460 000000006ec52570
0x00000083253ff330:   000001f0ff92b000 00000083253ff410
0x00000083253ff340:   000001f0ff93ff00 00000083253ff518
0x00000083253ff350:   000001f0ff93ff00 00007ffd3e3a5d21
0x00000083253ff360:   00000083253ff390 000001f0fdf20000
0x00000083253ff370:   00000083253ff460 0000000000000000
0x00000083253ff380:   000000006ec534e0 000000006ec53bc8
0x00000083253ff390:   00000083253ff3c0 000000006ec52621
0x00000083253ff3a0:   00000083253ff330 000001f0ff92b310
0x00000083253ff3b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x00000083253ff3c0:   00000083253ff460 000000006ec41575
0x00000083253ff3d0:   000000000000001c 000001f000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006ec4b5bb)
0x000000006ec4b4bb:   48 85 c0 74 bf 44 8b 03 45 85 c0 0f 84 77 ff ff
0x000000006ec4b4cb:   ff eb 9f 66 90 e8 8b fe ff ff 48 89 05 2c 34 01
0x000000006ec4b4db:   00 eb ad 66 90 e8 7b fe ff ff 48 89 05 1c 34 01
0x000000006ec4b4eb:   00 eb 8b e8 8d fe ff ff c7 03 01 00 00 00 e9 6f
0x000000006ec4b4fb:   ff ff ff 66 90 55 48 89 e5 56 53 48 83 ec 20 48
0x000000006ec4b50b:   8b 05 f7 33 01 00 48 8b 31 48 89 cb 48 85 c0 74
0x000000006ec4b51b:   56 44 8b 18 45 85 db 78 42 48 8b 05 dd 33 01 00
0x000000006ec4b52b:   48 85 c0 74 50 44 8b 10 45 85 d2 74 1d 48 89 f1
0x000000006ec4b53b:   e8 d0 fd ff ff 48 8b 13 48 8d 42 40 48 8b 48 08
0x000000006ec4b54b:   48 8b 6a 40 48 8b 60 10 ff e1 48 8b 05 bc 33 01
0x000000006ec4b55b:   00 48 85 c0 74 2d 48 89 30 eb da e8 b5 fe ff ff
0x000000006ec4b56b:   0f 1f 44 00 00 eb b2 e8 e9 fd ff ff 48 89 05 8a
0x000000006ec4b57b:   33 01 00 eb 9c e8 db fd ff ff 48 89 05 7c 33 01
0x000000006ec4b58b:   00 eb a2 e8 3d fd ff ff 48 89 05 7e 33 01 00 eb
0x000000006ec4b59b:   c5 0f 1f 40 00 55 57 56 53 48 83 ec 28 48 8b 05
0x000000006ec4b5ab:   59 33 01 00 48 89 cb 48 85 c0 0f 84 c5 00 00 00
0x000000006ec4b5bb:   8b 38 85 ff 0f 88 ab 00 00 00 48 8b 05 3c 33 01
0x000000006ec4b5cb:   00 48 85 c0 0f 84 bc 00 00 00 8b 30 85 f6 74 57
0x000000006ec4b5db:   48 8b 05 2e 33 01 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 e5 00 00 00
0x000000006ec4b5eb:   8b 28 48 8b 35 30 5e 01 00 ff d6 89 c7 89 e9 ff
0x000000006ec4b5fb:   15 14 5f 01 00 89 f9 48 89 c5 ff 15 d9 5e 01 00
0x000000006ec4b60b:   48 8b 05 fe 32 01 00 48 89 2b 48 85 c0 74 46 48
0x000000006ec4b61b:   89 da 8b 08 ff 15 f7 5e 01 00 85 c0 74 27 48 83
0x000000006ec4b62b:   c4 28 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 48 8b 05 df 32 01 00 48 85
0x000000006ec4b63b:   c0 74 64 48 8b 10 48 89 13 48 89 18 48 83 c4 28
0x000000006ec4b64b:   5b 5e 5f 5d c3 48 89 f2 48 83 c4 28 5b 5e 5f 5d
0x000000006ec4b65b:   48 ff e2 66 90 e8 8b fc ff ff 48 89 05 a4 32 01
0x000000006ec4b66b:   00 eb ac 66 90 e8 ab fd ff ff e9 4b ff ff ff 66
0x000000006ec4b67b:   0f 1f 44 00 00 e8 db fc ff ff 48 89 05 7c 32 01
0x000000006ec4b68b:   00 e9 2a ff ff ff e8 ca fc ff ff 48 89 05 6b 32
0x000000006ec4b69b:   01 00 e9 33 ff ff ff e8 29 fc ff ff 48 89 05 6a
0x000000006ec4b6ab:   32 01 00 48 8b 10 48 85 c0 48 89 13 75 8b e8 12 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x000001f0a0add1e0 points into unknown readable memory: 5c 00 5c 00 2e 00 5c 00
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x000001f0ff93fc90 points into unknown readable memory: 40 42 01 fe f0 01 00 00
stack at sp + 2 slots: 0x000000006ec4b210 jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x000001f0fdf20000 points into unknown readable memory: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x000001f0fe020000 points into unknown readable memory: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x0000000000000004 is an unknown value
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x000001f0ff92b310 points into unknown readable memory: a0 1a 55 03 fd 7f 00 00
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x0000000000000430 is an unknown value


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000001f0a09fee80, length=12, elements={
0x000001f0ff92b000, 0x000001f09ff7e800, 0x000001f0a0857000, 0x000001f0a0894800,
0x000001f0a0899800, 0x000001f0a087b000, 0x000001f0a08a5000, 0x000001f0a089a000,
0x000001f0a08ba000, 0x000001f0a0a06800, 0x000001f0a0a71800, 0x000001f0a0a76000
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x000001f0ff92b000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=6508, stack(0x0000008325300000,0x0000008325400000)]
  0x000001f09ff7e800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14404, stack(0x0000008325a00000,0x0000008325b00000)]
  0x000001f0a0857000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9620, stack(0x0000008325b00000,0x0000008325c00000)]
  0x000001f0a0894800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15124, stack(0x0000008325c00000,0x0000008325d00000)]
  0x000001f0a0899800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14376, stack(0x0000008325d00000,0x0000008325e00000)]
  0x000001f0a087b000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8268, stack(0x0000008325e00000,0x0000008325f00000)]
  0x000001f0a08a5000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14536, stack(0x0000008325f00000,0x0000008326000000)]
  0x000001f0a089a000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7844, stack(0x0000008326000000,0x0000008326100000)]
  0x000001f0a08ba000 JavaThread "Sweeper thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15020, stack(0x0000008326100000,0x0000008326200000)]
  0x000001f0a0a06800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=15240, stack(0x0000008326200000,0x0000008326300000)]
  0x000001f0a0a71800 JavaThread "Notification Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9880, stack(0x0000008326300000,0x0000008326400000)]
  0x000001f0a0a76000 JavaThread "Common-Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1992, stack(0x0000008326500000,0x0000008326600000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000001f09ff7c000 VMThread "VM Thread" [stack: 0x0000008325900000,0x0000008325a00000] [id=13200]
  0x000001f0a0a60800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000008326400000,0x0000008326500000] [id=13660]
  0x000001f0ff997000 GCTaskThread "GC Thread#0" [stack: 0x0000008325400000,0x0000008325500000] [id=14620]
  0x000001f0ff9b9000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Main Marker" [stack: 0x0000008325500000,0x0000008325600000] [id=14104]
  0x000001f0ff9ba000 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Conc#0" [stack: 0x0000008325600000,0x0000008325700000] [id=9584]
  0x000001f09fe5d800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Refine#0" [stack: 0x0000008325700000,0x0000008325800000] [id=14980]
  0x000001f09fe60800 ConcurrentGCThread "G1 Young RemSet Sampling" [stack: 0x0000008325800000,0x0000008325900000] [id=8196]

Threads with active compile tasks:

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap address: 0x0000000701000000, size: 4080 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000800000000, Narrow klass shift: 0
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x0000000800000000

Heap:
 garbage-first heap   total 262144K, used 1024K [0x0000000701000000, 0x0000000800000000)
  region size 1024K, 2 young (2048K), 0 survivors (0K)
 Metaspace       used 4428K, capacity 4600K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 398K, capacity 432K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
Heap Regions: E=young(eden), S=young(survivor), O=old, HS=humongous(starts), HC=humongous(continues), CS=collection set, F=free, OA=open archive, CA=closed archive, TAMS=top-at-mark-start (previous, next)

I DELETED A LARGE AMOUNT OF INFO HERE BECAUSE IT SEEMED REPETITIVE AND PUT ME OVER CHARACTER LIMIT. LET ME KNOW IF I SHOULD INCLUDE IT.

Card table byte_map: [0x000001f093ea0000,0x000001f0946a0000] _byte_map_base: 0x000001f090698000

Marking Bits (Prev, Next): (CMBitMap*) 0x000001f0ff997a18, (CMBitMap*) 0x000001f0ff997a58
 Prev Bits: [0x000001f094ea0000, 0x000001f098e60000)
 Next Bits: [0x000001f098e60000, 0x000001f09ce20000)

Polling page: 0x000001f0fe0b0000

Metaspace:

Usage:
  Non-class:      4.07 MB capacity,     3.94 MB ( 97%) used,   138.20 KB (  3%) free+waste,   256 bytes ( <1%) overhead. 
      Class:    432.00 KB capacity,   398.85 KB ( 92%) used,    32.52 KB (  8%) free+waste,   640 bytes ( <1%) overhead. 
       Both:      4.49 MB capacity,     4.32 MB ( 96%) used,   170.73 KB (  4%) free+waste,   896 bytes ( <1%) overhead. 

Virtual space:
  Non-class space:        8.00 MB reserved,       4.25 MB ( 53%) committed 
      Class space:        1.00 GB reserved,     512.00 KB ( <1%) committed 
             Both:        1.01 GB reserved,       4.75 MB ( <1%) committed 

Chunk freelists:
   Non-Class:  56.00 KB
       Class:  16.00 KB
        Both:  72.00 KB

MaxMetaspaceSize: 17179869184.00 GB
CompressedClassSpaceSize: 1.00 GB

CodeHeap 'non-profiled nmethods': size=119168Kb used=20Kb max_used=20Kb free=119147Kb
 bounds [0x000001f08b790000, 0x000001f08ba00000, 0x000001f092bf0000]
CodeHeap 'profiled nmethods': size=119104Kb used=151Kb max_used=151Kb free=118952Kb
 bounds [0x000001f084340000, 0x000001f0845b0000, 0x000001f08b790000]
CodeHeap 'non-nmethods': size=7488Kb used=1622Kb max_used=1622Kb free=5866Kb
 bounds [0x000001f083bf0000, 0x000001f083e60000, 0x000001f084340000]
 total_blobs=389 nmethods=109 adapters=192
 compilation: enabled
              stopped_count=0, restarted_count=0
 full_count=0

Compilation events (20 events):
Event: 0.103 Thread 0x000001f0a089a000 nmethod 99 0x000001f084360510 code [0x000001f0843607c0, 0x000001f084361a38]
Event: 0.103 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 100 0x000001f084361f10 code [0x000001f0843620c0, 0x000001f0843622f8]
Event: 0.104 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  101       3       java.lang.Math::min (11 bytes)
Event: 0.104 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 101 0x000001f084362410 code [0x000001f0843625a0, 0x000001f0843626d8]
Event: 0.106 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  102       3       java.lang.StringBuilder::append (8 bytes)
Event: 0.106 Thread 0x000001f0a089a000  103       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::append (45 bytes)
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 102 0x000001f084362790 code [0x000001f084362940, 0x000001f084362a88]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  104       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::putStringAt (29 bytes)
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 104 0x000001f084362b10 code [0x000001f084362ce0, 0x000001f084362fd8]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  105       3       java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder::getCoder (15 bytes)
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 105 0x000001f084363110 code [0x000001f0843632a0, 0x000001f0843633d8]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  106       3       java.lang.String::indexOf (7 bytes)
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a089a000 nmethod 103 0x000001f084363490 code [0x000001f0843636a0, 0x000001f084363bb8]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 106 0x000001f084363e10 code [0x000001f084363fe0, 0x000001f0843642d8]
Event: 0.107 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  107       3       java.util.Arrays::copyOfRange (64 bytes)
Event: 0.108 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 107 0x000001f084364410 code [0x000001f0843646a0, 0x000001f084365218]
Event: 0.109 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800  108       3       java.lang.System::getSecurityManager (12 bytes)
Event: 0.109 Thread 0x000001f0a089a000  109       3       java.lang.System::allowSecurityManager (13 bytes)
Event: 0.109 Thread 0x000001f0a089a000 nmethod 109 0x000001f084365690 code [0x000001f084365820, 0x000001f084365918]
Event: 0.109 Thread 0x000001f0a0a06800 nmethod 108 0x000001f084365990 code [0x000001f084365b40, 0x000001f084365cb8]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (4 events):
Event: 0.078 Thread 0x000001f0ff92b000 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff45 fr.pc=0x000001f08b794d6c relative=0x000000000000020c
Event: 0.078 Thread 0x000001f0ff92b000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000001f08b794d6c method=java.lang.String.hashCode()I @ 42 c2
Event: 0.078 Thread 0x000001f0ff92b000 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x000001f08b794d6c sp=0x00000083253fd690
Event: 0.078 Thread 0x000001f0ff92b000 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x000001f083c3912f sp=0x00000083253fd628 mode 2

Classes unloaded (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (20 events):
Event: 0.104 loading class java/lang/PublicMethods$Key
Event: 0.104 loading class java/lang/PublicMethods$Key done
Event: 0.104 loading class java/lang/Void
Event: 0.104 loading class java/lang/Void done
Event: 0.105 Loaded shared library C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\verify.dll
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/InterruptedException
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/InterruptedException done
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/NoSuchMethodException
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/NoSuchMethodException done
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/SecurityException
Event: 0.105 loading class java/lang/SecurityException done
Event: 0.105 loading class java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode
Event: 0.105 loading class java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$ForwardingNode done
Event: 0.108 loading class java/io/Reader
Event: 0.108 loading class java/lang/Readable
Event: 0.108 loading class java/lang/Readable done
Event: 0.108 loading class java/io/Reader done
Event: 0.108 loading class java/io/InputStreamReader
Event: 0.108 loading class java/io/InputStreamReader done
Event: 0.110 Loaded shared library C:\Users\Michael\.jssc\windows\jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff79cac0000 - 0x00007ff79cacd000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffd3e390000 - 0x00007ffd3e586000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffd3c6c0000 - 0x00007ffd3c77d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffd3bc30000 - 0x00007ffd3bef8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffd3c0c0000 - 0x00007ffd3c1c0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ffd2f7c0000 - 0x00007ffd2f7d5000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\VCRUNTIME140.dll
0x00007ffd2f7e0000 - 0x00007ffd2f7f8000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\jli.dll
0x00007ffd2d190000 - 0x00007ffd2d42b000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.488_none_ca04af081b815d21\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ffd3ce10000 - 0x00007ffd3cfb0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffd3de00000 - 0x00007ffd3de9e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffd3c010000 - 0x00007ffd3c032000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ffd3d4f0000 - 0x00007ffd3d51a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffd3bf00000 - 0x00007ffd3c009000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ffd3c220000 - 0x00007ffd3c2bd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ffd3d520000 - 0x00007ffd3d550000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffd2f1a0000 - 0x00007ffd2f23b000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\msvcp140.dll
0x00007ffd02b90000 - 0x00007ffd036ae000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffd3d600000 - 0x00007ffd3d6ac000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffd3c400000 - 0x00007ffd3c49b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffd3e220000 - 0x00007ffd3e344000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffd3d260000 - 0x00007ffd3d268000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffd2ead0000 - 0x00007ffd2eaf7000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffd31900000 - 0x00007ffd3190a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ffd243a0000 - 0x00007ffd243a9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffd3c800000 - 0x00007ffd3c86b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffd39a40000 - 0x00007ffd39a52000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ffd36670000 - 0x00007ffd3667a000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\jimage.dll
0x00007ffd23a20000 - 0x00007ffd23c04000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DBGHELP.DLL
0x00007ffd242d0000 - 0x00007ffd242fc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbgcore.DLL
0x00007ffd3c370000 - 0x00007ffd3c3ef000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ffd11fa0000 - 0x00007ffd11fc5000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ffd36490000 - 0x00007ffd364a6000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ffd3d6b0000 - 0x00007ffd3ddf1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffd39c40000 - 0x00007ffd3a3d5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ffd3dec0000 - 0x00007ffd3e215000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ffd3b540000 - 0x00007ffd3b56c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Wldp.dll
0x00007ffd3c610000 - 0x00007ffd3c6be000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffd3d1a0000 - 0x00007ffd3d1f5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ffd3ba00000 - 0x00007ffd3ba26000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffd32280000 - 0x00007ffd32299000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ffd33480000 - 0x00007ffd33580000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll
0x00007ffd3b250000 - 0x00007ffd3b2ba000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ffd2f100000 - 0x00007ffd2f112000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ffd35df0000 - 0x00007ffd35e00000     C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006ec40000 - 0x000000006ec65000     C:\Users\Michael\.jssc\windows\jSSC-2.7_x86_64.dll

dbghelp: loaded successfully - version: 4.0.5 - missing functions: none
symbol engine: initialized successfully - sym options: 0x614 - pdb path: .;C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.488_none_ca04af081b815d21;C:\Users\Michael\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932\jre\bin\server;C:\Users\Michael\.jssc\windows

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages 
java_command: SerialTest
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Michael\eclipse-workspace\JSSC\bin;C:\Users\Michael\Downloads\jSSC-2.7.0-Release\jSSC-2.7.0-Release\jssc.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

[Global flags]
     intx CICompilerCount                          = 12                                        {product} {ergonomic}
     uint ConcGCThreads                            = 3                                         {product} {ergonomic}
     uint G1ConcRefinementThreads                  = 13                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t G1HeapRegionSize                         = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx GCDrainStackTargetSize                   = 64                                        {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t InitialHeapSize                          = 268435456                                 {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MarkStackSize                            = 4194304                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxHeapSize                              = 4278190080                                {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MaxNewSize                               = 2566914048                                {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapDeltaBytes                        = 1048576                                   {product} {ergonomic}
   size_t MinHeapSize                              = 8388608                                   {product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonNMethodCodeHeapSize                   = 7602480                                {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx NonProfiledCodeHeapSize                  = 122027880                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ProfiledCodeHeapSize                     = 122027880                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
    uintx ReservedCodeCacheSize                    = 251658240                              {pd product} {ergonomic}
     bool SegmentedCodeCache                       = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages       = true                                   {manageable} {command line}
   size_t SoftMaxHeapSize                          = 4278190080                             {manageable} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedClassPointers               = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseCompressedOops                        = true                                 {lp64_product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseG1GC                                  = true                                      {product} {ergonomic}
     bool UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation        = false                                  {pd product} {ergonomic}

Logging:
Log output configuration:
 #0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
 #1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:/Users/Michael/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin/server;C:/Users/Michael/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_14.0.2.v20200815-0932/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Progra
USERNAME=Michael
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 8 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10 , 64 bit Build 19041 (10.0.19041.546)
OS uptime: 0 days 0:09 hours

CPU:total 16 (initial active 16) (16 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 23 model 8 stepping 2, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv, bmi1, bmi2, adx, sha, fma

Memory: 4k page, system-wide physical 16315M (11027M free)
TotalPageFile size 24507M (AvailPageFile size 16520M)
current process WorkingSet (physical memory assigned to process): 32M, peak: 32M
current process commit charge ("private bytes"): 348M, peak: 348M

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0.2+12-46) for windows-amd64 JRE (14.0.2+12-46), built on Jul  9 2020 00:31:16 by "mach5one" with MS VC++ 15.9 (VS2017)

END.
```

**What I have tried:**
So far, I have gone to advanced settings an switched to Minidump. I have reinstalled all my drivers, updated Windows 10, and redownloaded Java SDK. I am currently using Eclipse IDE and have also deleted the .metadata folder as someone suggested it could help. I am really at a loss and am not entirely certain how to interpret the log file or the error in general.
This error only appears when I attempt to call JSSC's openPort method. It also appears when I attempt to use RXTX to accomplish the same purpose. Not really sure what is going on here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Someone found that using Java 1.8 helped: https://github.com/java-native/jssc/issues/65

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! Simply downloaded 2.9.1 from some obscure website. This is just a lesson to use Maven in future!

Comment: "2.9.1" of what? Which "obscure" website? Why use Maven?